# Babel-node not found - Heroku Deploy

Tags: node.js, reactjs, mongodb, heroku, babeljs

I am trying to deploy a simple Ecommerce website that has **Reactjs , Node, Express and MongoDB**. I have followed a tutorial to deploy it to the **heroku**. I have used babel but in the tutorial, it wasn't used. I know we don't use **babel** for production and used only for the development purpose, but I am not sure how I would still deploy my website.

The server is working perfectly **locally** and also the Heroku build is successful. But when I visit my deployed app on heroku it says **application error**.

Here are the **logs from Heroku**:

```
2020-06-29T16:04:44.812179+00:00 heroku[web.1]: Starting process with command `npm start`
2020-06-29T16:04:48.072669+00:00 app[web.1]: 
2020-06-29T16:04:48.072690+00:00 app[web.1]: > e-commerce-site@1.0.0 start /app
2020-06-29T16:04:48.072691+00:00 app[web.1]: > babel-node backend/server.js
2020-06-29T16:04:48.072691+00:00 app[web.1]: 
2020-06-29T16:04:48.105827+00:00 app[web.1]: sh: 1: babel-node: not found
2020-06-29T16:04:48.110266+00:00 app[web.1]: npm ERR! code ELIFECYCLE
2020-06-29T16:04:48.111030+00:00 app[web.1]: npm ERR! syscall spawn
2020-06-29T16:04:48.111915+00:00 app[web.1]: npm ERR! file sh
2020-06-29T16:04:48.112482+00:00 app[web.1]: npm ERR! errno ENOENT
2020-06-29T16:04:48.114018+00:00 app[web.1]: npm ERR! e-commerce-site@1.0.0 start: `babel-node backend/server.js`
2020-06-29T16:04:48.114155+00:00 app[web.1]: npm ERR! spawn ENOENT
2020-06-29T16:04:48.114342+00:00 app[web.1]: npm ERR!
2020-06-29T16:04:48.114508+00:00 app[web.1]: npm ERR! Failed at the e-commerce-site@1.0.0 start script.
2020-06-29T16:04:48.114601+00:00 app[web.1]: npm ERR! This is probably not a problem with npm. There is likely additional logging output above.
2020-06-29T16:04:48.133545+00:00 app[web.1]: 
2020-06-29T16:04:48.134148+00:00 app[web.1]: npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
2020-06-29T16:04:48.134771+00:00 app[web.1]: npm ERR!     /app/.npm/_logs/2020-06- 
29T16_04_48_124Z-debug.log
2020-06-29T16:04:48.213867+00:00 heroku[web.1]: Process exited with status 1
2020-06-29T16:04:48.265610+00:00 heroku[web.1]: State changed from starting to crashed
2020-06-29T16:04:48.268292+00:00 heroku[web.1]: State changed from crashed to starting
2020-06-29T16:04:57.328678+00:00 heroku[web.1]: Starting process with command `npm start`
2020-06-29T16:05:00.299582+00:00 app[web.1]: 
2020-06-29T16:05:00.299595+00:00 app[web.1]: > e-commerce-site@1.0.0 start /app
2020-06-29T16:05:00.299595+00:00 app[web.1]: > babel-node backend/server.js
2020-06-29T16:05:00.299596+00:00 app[web.1]: 
2020-06-29T16:05:00.308802+00:00 app[web.1]: sh: 1: babel-node: not found
2020-06-29T16:05:00.312668+00:00 app[web.1]: npm ERR! code ELIFECYCLE
2020-06-29T16:05:00.313206+00:00 app[web.1]: npm ERR! syscall spawn
2020-06-29T16:05:00.313637+00:00 app[web.1]: npm ERR! file sh
2020-06-29T16:05:00.314093+00:00 app[web.1]: npm ERR! errno ENOENT
2020-06-29T16:05:00.315953+00:00 app[web.1]: npm ERR! e-commerce-site@1.0.0 start: `babel-node backend/server.js`
2020-06-29T16:05:00.316283+00:00 app[web.1]: npm ERR! spawn ENOENT
2020-06-29T16:05:00.316613+00:00 app[web.1]: npm ERR!
2020-06-29T16:05:00.316974+00:00 app[web.1]: npm ERR! Failed at the e-commerce-site@1.0.0 start script.
2020-06-29T16:05:00.317312+00:00 app[web.1]: npm ERR! This is probably not a problem with npm. There is likely additional logging output above.
2020-06-29T16:05:00.344371+00:00 app[web.1]: 
2020-06-29T16:05:00.344828+00:00 app[web.1]: npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
2020-06-29T16:05:00.345202+00:00 app[web.1]: npm ERR!     /app/.npm/_logs/2020-06-29T16_05_00_319Z-debug.log
2020-06-29T16:05:00.406294+00:00 heroku[web.1]: Process exited with status 1
2020-06-29T16:05:00.466244+00:00 heroku[web.1]: State changed from starting to crashed
```

**File Name: Server.js**

The file where I have all the connections for MongoDB:

```
import express from "express";
import data from "./data";
import dotenv from "dotenv";
import config from "./config";
import mongoose from "mongoose";
import userRoute from "./routes/userRoute";
import productRoute from "./routes/productRoute";
import bodyParser from "body-parser";

dotenv.config();
const mongodbUrl = config.MONGODB_URL;
const PORT = process.env.PORT || 5000;

mongoose.connect(mongodbUrl , {
    useNewUrlParser : true,
    useUnifiedTopology: true,
    useCreateIndex: true
}).catch(error => console.log(error.reason));


const app = express();
app.use(bodyParser.json());

app.use("/api/users" , userRoute);
app.use("/api/products" , productRoute);

if (process.env.NODE_ENV === "production"){
    app.use(express.static("./frontend/build"));
}
app.listen(PORT , console.log(`Server started at ${PORT}`));
```

**File Name: config.js**

```
export default{
    MONGODB_URL: process.env.MONGODB_URL || "mongodb://localhost/ecommercesite",
    JWT_SECRET: process.env.JWT_SECRET || "somethingsecret"
}
```

**File Name: Package.json**

```
{
  "name": "e-commerce-site",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "description": "",
  "main": "index.js",
  "scripts": {
    
    "build" : "cd frontend && npm run build",
    "install-client" : "cd frontend && npm install",
    "heroku-postbuild" : "npm run install-client && npm run build",
    "start": "babel-node backend/server.js"
  },
  "author": "",
  "license": "ISC",
  "dependencies": {
    "axios": "^0.19.2",
    "body-parser": "^1.19.0",
    "dotenv": "^8.2.0",
    "express": "^4.17.1",
    "jsonwebtoken": "^8.5.1",
    "mongoose": "^5.9.16"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@babel/cli": "^7.10.1",
    "@babel/core": "^7.10.1",
    "@babel/node": "^7.10.1",
    "@babel/preset-env": "^7.10.1",
    "nodemon": "^2.0.4"
  }
}
```

Comment: Does it work if you install `@babel/node` as a dependency instead of a devDependency? That is, move the `@babel/node` from `devDependencies` into `dependencies`, run `npm i` and push the changed package.json and package-lock.json.

Comment: I have tried exactly as you said and I face the same error.
Added a few lines of the logs

2020-06-29T16:36:48.000000+00:00 app[api]: Build succeeded
2020-06-29T16:37:02.582334+00:00 heroku[web.1]: Starting process with command `npm start`
2020-06-29T16:37:05.114621+00:00 app[web.1]: Error: Cannot find module '@babel/core'

Comment: Well, sounds like it's a different error! Move all of the `@babel` errors into `dependencies`.

Comment: I tried it too it still doesn't want to work.

Comment: What's the error after that?

Comment: 2020-06-29T18:14:50.014451+00:00 app[web.1]: > babel-node backend/server.js
2020-06-29T18:14:51.197991+00:00 app[web.1]: (node:35) Warning: To load an ES module, set "type": "module" in the package.json or use the .mjs extension.
2020-06-29T18:14:51.201667+00:00 app[web.1]: /app/backend/server.js:1
2020-06-29T18:14:51.201668+00:00 app[web.1]: import express from "express";
2020-06-29T18:14:51.201668+00:00 app[web.1]: ^^^^^^
2020-06-29T18:14:51.201669+00:00 app[web.1]: 
2020-06-29T18:14:51.201669+00:00 app[web.1]: SyntaxError: Cannot use import statement outside a module